# fos elasticabundle mapping type "array"

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, elastica

I have a doctrine array in column "tags" in table/entity "category".

FOS ElasticaBundle is up and working, and now I want to add the "tags" column to the search.

I cannot find any resources on how to set this up. Here is what I've tried and would like to do.

```
  search:
        client: default
        types:
            category:
                mappings:
                    displayName: ~
                    searchRef: ~
                    tags:
                        type: 'array'
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: SC\ProviderBundle\Entity\Category
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

I have three other types that use mapping type "nested" than run fine. The array expected has no keys, so I don't know what to put down for properties.

I'm getting this error

```
[Elastica\Exception\ResponseException]
 MapperParsingException[mapping [category]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [array] declared on field [tags]];
```

How do I set my mapping type "tags" as an array in Symfony2 using FOSElasticaBundle and where is this in any documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

```
type:
    category:
        mappings:
            tags:
                type: 'string'
```

as described here

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html

( working link, but idk if it's same page, someone feel free to edit and improve this answer  ) 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-array-type.html

Comment: what if i have an array of objects ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have copied it down! Elasticsearch has no idea how to keep consistent links they change their site waaay too much. Every useful link I find online is broken or outdated with no easy way to find new information about that topic.

Answer (score 3):

Came across the same question myself.
For the newest version of elasticsearch (v4) the type needs to be 'text':

```
type:
    category:
        mappings:
            tags:
                type: 'text'
```

Comment: if your field contains less than 256 characters, *keyword* data type is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this config:

```
    types:
        category:
            mappings:
                displayName: ~
                searchRef: ~
                tags:
                    type: nested
                    properties:
                         yourTagProperty: ~
```